# Passing parameters to webapi from Kendo dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

Does anyone know how I can pass parameters to my webapi server from Kendo dropdownlist?

I tried using parametermap in the datasource in the same way that I successfully pass parameters from my Kendogrid but the parametermap code doesn't seem to get executed from the dropdownlist.

Basically I need to restrict my dropdown to a set of values which are an appropriate subset of the main dataset from sql server.

Comment: Just to add a bit more colour - the parametermap code DOES get executed (contrary to my earlier post) but when I stop my code in the visual studio debugger in the Get method the class variable which I had hoped would contain my parameters is always null.

Comment: Without code, it's going to be hard to troubleshoot this. Adding code to your question is always helpful...more info = better answers.

Comment: I just used signalR for the lookups in the end - thanks guys!